# Same page Hyperlink with PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to link to another part of a php page.  So $x is a value I've pulled from an array that is a hyperlink.

```
echo "<a href='#{$x}'>{$x}</a>" . " ";
```

However I am stuck in linking to the target id on the same page.

```
echo '<a id="$x">' . '<h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($x))).' ' . 'offers'.'</h2>'.'</a>';
```

Sure when I hover over the link, it is passing the correct value of $x in the query string, but not linking to the  because I am coding the target id part wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Volterony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to visit a ID on on the page use `href="#id"`

```
echo '<a href="#'.$x.'">' . '<h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($x))).' ' . 'offers'.'</h2>'.'</a>';
```

Improved Code

```
echo '<a href="#'.$x.'"><h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($x))). 'offers </h2></a>';
```

Comment: Awesome Basic Bridge.  I am not a season PHP pro like a lot of people on stackoverflow, so will probably get punished (by down vote) a lot for making small errors :)  We all started somewhere.

Comment: BasicBridge your answer doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Your answer did answer my question Basic Bridge.  Cheers

Comment: Upvote. You picked up separation correctly. Downvoters, please re-consider his answer.

Comment: @Volterony I improved the code with proper seperation

Comment: Not a Problem Toby Allen.  I would not have researched if you hadn't point this out.  Thanks for the reversal.

Comment: Excellent Basic Bridge. Nice Clean up Job!!